# 32-bit version of udev and usb library in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, udev, libraries, 32bit

I had a project which uses `libudev` and `libusb` libraries.

Operating System: Ubuntu 18.04 64-bit

Initially the application was 64-bit, so there was no issue.

Now, there is a new requirement of supporting 32-bit. When i tried to compile by adding `-m32` to my build Makefile, it throws the following error.

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ludev
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libusb-1.0.so when searching for -lusb-1.0
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libusb-1.0.a when searching for -lusb-1.0
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lusb-1.0
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I used the following commands to install 64-bit versions:

```
sudo apt-get install libudev-dev
sudo apt-get install libusb-1.0-0-dev
```

I tried the following command but it didn't work

```
sudo apt-get install libudev1:i386
```

What is the command to install 32-bit version of these libraries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install the `i386` development packages:

```
sudo apt install libudev-dev:i386 libusb-1.0-0-dev:i386
```

These two are co-installable with their `amd64` versions so you won’t need to uninstall anything.